# Which is the most efficient way of comparing large number of value which are stored in array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have thousands of values stored in an array in Java. I want to compare each value with every other value in the array.

Currently I am comparing using two nested loops. This method leads to heap space memory error.

Below is my code which I am currently using:

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1; j<arr.size(); j++)
    {
        //CODE FOR COMPARING arr[i] and arr[j]
        //performing some more operations here which contain loops and functions
    }
}
```

Which is the most efficient way for comparing such a large amount of data?

**Edit:**
I am executing this using eclipse.

It is ArrayList is of type string.

I am comparing using ".equals"

I am also performing some more operations inside the loop which takes some more memory.

I even tried to put a print count inside the loop to know how many times the loop has been executed. It had executed for more than 32K times.

Comment: it depends on what you want to compare, and what the type of arr is.

Comment: Also, do you want to compare for equality (==) or compare which one is greater?

Comment: How is this using any more memory than the original array?

Comment: Do the starting arrays have any special properties, like sorted?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your type, you can either

- sort the array and use a binary sort `O(N log N)`
- add the elements to a HashMap and lookup any matchs `O(N)` though this depends on what you are doing with the values.

A good pattern for Java 8 is to use either a groupingBy, or a reduction.

```
Map<String, List<MyType>> map = Stream.of(arr)
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(mt -> mt.getKey()));
```

What this does is combine all the entries with the same key.  You can pick a key to suit your comparison.  This will combine all the entries with the same key into a collection and then you only need match the entries which have the same key.  This groupingBy takes `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your memory ends, because you allocate too large arrays. So you may insert your values in a HashMap while you read them, thus avoiding duplicates to enter and you may save memory. Adding to HashMap takes O(1) time and gives you false when this element was already inserted. Hope this helps.